# Sequence of linear automorphisms on $\mathbb{R}^m$ stretching the norm to infinity on integer-valued vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

This is one of those questions so elementary that it is almost too embarrassing to ask. But since I am fairly stuck, here we go:

Let a number $m\in\mathbb{N}$ be fixed. Suppose that $\sigma_n: \mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^m$ is a sequence of linear automorphisms with the following properties:

1) Each automorphisms maps $\mathbb{Z}^m$ into itself, i.e. $\sigma_n(\mathbb{Z}^m)\subseteq\mathbb{Z}^m$ for all $n$.

2) For all $0\neq v\in\mathbb{Z}^m$, we have $\|\sigma_n(v)\|\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$. (Pick any norm on $\mathbb{R}^m$, for instance $\|\cdot\|_\infty$.)

> **Question:** Does the sequence of inverses $\sigma_n^{-1}: \mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^m$ converge to zero? (pointwise)

Since I cannot even manage to show an a-priori weaker statement, let me also include it:

> **Weaker Question:** Is it true that $\|\sigma_n(x)\|\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$, for all $0\neq x\in\mathbb{R}^m$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking $m=2$ and $\sigma_n=\pmatrix{1/n&0\\n^2&n}$ for $n\geq1$, whose inverse is $\sigma_n^{-1}=\pmatrix{n&0\\-n^2&1/n}$, one sees that for any nonzero $v\in \Bbb R^2$ one has $\lim_{n\to\infty}\|\sigma_n(v)\|=\infty$. However $\|\sigma_n^{-1}(v)\|$ only tends to$~0$ for multiples of the second standard basis vector; for other vectors it tends to$~\infty$.

For a counterexample to the weaker question just take matrices with a fixed basis of "irrational angle" eigenvectors, and eigenvalues $1/n$ and $n$ (the images of the former eigenvector tend to $0$, but not those of any rational vector).

Comment: Thank you very much! Unfortunately, I was a bit sloppy asking the question and forgot another condition... (I have edited the question accordingly) It is unclear to me if such a counterexample fits into that more special framework.